# Design pattern for message packet header

Tags: c++, design-patterns, messaging

I am writing my own messaging API using `libevent`. The data is wrapped by a packet structure which contains a `packet body` of data byte array and a `packet header` that contains the entire packet size information (for the reason to invoke callback at a complete stream).

```
class PacketHeader {
  size_t packet_size;
};

class Packet {
  PacketHeader header;
  uint8_t* body;
};
```

However, I wanna users be able to customize their own PacketHeader, while I can handle the underlying size information for messaging. What is the best practice to do this? Should I use inheritance or pure virtual abstraction (interface class). I was thinking about the following but not sure if it is the best practice.

```
template <class Derived>
class PacketHeader{
  size_t packet_size;
  size_t header_size() const {return sizeof(Derived);}
}
```

Comment: Pure virtual `PacketHeader` with your standard `PacketHeader` implemented as a basis, only containing the `packet_size`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the inheritance stuff, why not make the packets self describing, i.e. something like:

```
struct packet_header {
  int16_t size;   // size_t is too big
  uint8_t header; // header size
  uint8_t type;   // header type, some sort of id for header/message
};
```

Then users can define their own header types with sizes, a message would be composed as follows:

```
[  ][ ][ ]<--custom header-->[--body--]
```

So the `custom header` block is optional and the size is specified in the packet header. Then allow user specific code to decode the header appropriately.